# Jquery "On" method is not working in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using following jquery -

1. Jquery 1.11.1
2. Jquery Mobile 1.4.2

But I am not able to call pagecreate method in my code. However it works fine with document.ready. Also, I tried with older version of Jquery and replaced "on" with "live" it worked. But "live" has been deprecated after version 1.9.  I have to use Jquery1.11.1.  Following is my code-

```
  $("#demo").on("pagecreate",function() {

    //Do something  (Control is not jumping here)
  });
```

Comment: Is `#demo` the ID of your body tag? HTML tag? You should use `$(document).on('pagecreate', function() {});`

Comment: Delegate it. `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#demo", function`.

Comment: @scrowler without delegation, the event will fire on each page.

Comment: demo is the id of my page. Here is the code- <div data-role="page" id="demo">

Comment: $(document).on("pagecreate", "#demo",function() worked for me. Thanks guys.